# Missing required architecture x86_64 even after removing x86_64 requirement

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, static-libraries

I have an Objective-C static library that I want to add to my Swift project. First problem is that the library doesn't have x86_64 requirements. Naturally, I removed that under my target's Build Settings and instead only include `arm64`, `armv7`, and `armv7s`. I chose these based off of the lip output for my library:

```
lipo -info libMobileImagingEngine.a 
Architectures in the fat file: libMobileImagingEngine.a are: arm64 armv7 armv7s
```

Here's a screen cap of my Architectures tab:
[image]

But I still get two warnings:

> Ignoring file [filepath here] missing required architecture i386 in
>   file [filepath again] (3 Slices)

and

> Ignoring file [filepath here] missing required architecture x86_64 in
>   file [filepath again] (3 Slices)

Comment: your framework or library is build for particular architecture of device, then it will only work with that specific architecture. check your framework or library architecture, otherwise build again for specific one. use following command to check architecture of file `xcrun -sdk iphoneos lipo -info $(FILENAME)`

Comment: @Dipen The archs that the library will compile for are already known and put that output in my question. My problem seems to be with Xcode with still wants i386 and x86_64 even though I removed those from the Architecture tab in my Build Settings.

Comment: you would be trying to run app in simulator which is build on i386 and your library is not build for that, try to run app on device, it would work.

Comment: @DipenPanchasara That seemed to be it! I found another build of the library I could import.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dipen made a good point about running the app on simulator, and that seemed to be the problem. I was able to find another build of the library I'm using and imported that one too. Now Xcode will simply ignore the irrelevant one per the device it's running on.